# Network switch is bottlenecking

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, switch, wifi-configuration

[image]I have 5 port gigabit switch and a 400 Mbps connection. I receive full  400 Mbps via 5Ghz Wifi through main router in which ISP's connection is connected. One CAt6 cable is connected to switch from router's LAN port . PC connected to switch is receiving full 400 Mbps speed. But the switch is unable to distribute the 400 Mbps speed to my two 100 Mbps Wifi Routers. I checked this on speedtest.net. When I started speed test on both of my 100 Mbps wifi routers via WIFI using two seperate mobile devices the speed on one router is 70 Mbps and on the second Wifi router the speed is around 1 Mbps but when I stop the test on one router the speed on second router starts increasing to 80 Mbps. singnal strenght of both my Wifi routers is excellent. I don't know where's the bottleneck is happenig. Kindly guide me please.

**Edit**:- **1** link speed between switch and PC is 1 Gigabit. **2** Link speed between switch and both the routers is 100 Mbps because routers WAN port only have 4 pins to make contact with RJ45 connector coming from the switch. **3** Connecting PC to these routers cables is giving me 1000 Mbps link speed as PC has a Gigabit ethernet card with 8 pins to make contact with RJ45 connector coming from the switch.
**EDIT** :- some strange thing i'm noticing is that one PC and two laptops connected to the switch using the same cables are making 1 Gbps link speeds and 400 Mbps internet speed is equally distributed among these 3 PC's with no speed loss.

Comment: Your switch isn’t to blame. In the first place, it isn’t even remotely busy if your old Wi-Fi routers are limited to less than 100 MBit/s. // Please provide a wiring diagram including the link speeds as indicates by the switch status LEDs.

Comment: Thank you for providing this diagram! It’s still missing the individual link speeds. Or, technically, just one: Between your router and the switch, did you make sure this is in fact running at 1000 MBit/s? Cat6 cable or not. // Also, you should try a test with your PC (wired) competing with a wireless device. Just to rule out wireless interference. // Which brings me to the next point: What are the wireless settings? Are they on non-overlapping channels?